# How to "%q" format a lua_Buffer in the C-API

Tags: c, api, lua, lua-api

[string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format)("%q", foo_str) will format a string to add the appropriate escape chars to make it safe to read back into the Lua interpreter. How can I best use this function to format a Lua_Buffer from the C-API?  More generally, how can I access the string.* functions from the C-API?  I could use [lua_pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall)("string.format", ...), but curious if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 2):

The `format` function is defined as static in the `lstrlib.c` module, so AFAIK the only way to get to it is through the `string` table.

I suppose you *could* look at `addquoted` in `lstrlib.c` and adjust it for your use, but probably easier to just call `string.format`.